# Hibernate : ClassCastException due to getter return type (only in unit tests in CI)

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, enums

I have an hibernate entity which contains an enum MyEnum. This enum is saved as a String, which is the name of the enum (we agree this is bad, since the enum's name could change).

To ease the use of this enum, the getter returns MyEnum and not String. Here's the code :

```
public class MyEntity{
  private String enumField;

  public MyEnum getEnumField(){
      return MyEnum.valueOf(enumField);
  }
}
```

We use hibernate-core 3.3.2.GA.

This is working fine in our unit tests, locally. However, when ran on our continuous integration (TeamCity) it fails when reading an entity :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.inetpsa.cob.outils.bean.EnumSurveillance cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at org.hibernate.type.StringType.toString(StringType.java:67)
 at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.toLoggableString(NullableType.java:239)
 at org.hibernate.pretty.Printer.toString(Printer.java:76)
 at org.hibernate.pretty.Printer.toString(Printer.java:113)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:120)
 at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:58)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:997)
 at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1142)
 at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$30.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:930)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:921)
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.find(HibernateTemplate.java:913)
```

I don't understand why the behaviour can be different localy and in TeamCity.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is there a difference between local and Team city?
--> localy hibernate debug is disabled, whereas on Team City it is enabled.

The issue comes from the pretty print done by hibernate in debug mode.

To get the property enumField, it uses the field's getter, as we can see in class AbstractEntityTuplizer :

```
public Object[] getPropertyValues(Object entity) throws HibernateException {
    boolean getAll = shouldGetAllProperties( entity );
    final int span = entityMetamodel.getPropertySpan();
    final Object[] result = new Object[span];

    for ( int j = 0; j < span; j++ ) {
        StandardProperty property = entityMetamodel.getProperties()[j];
        if ( getAll || !property.isLazy() ) {
            result[j] = getters[j].get( entity );
        }
        else {
            result[j] = LazyPropertyInitializer.UNFETCHED_PROPERTY;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In our case, the getter returns an object MyEnum.

In the pretty printer, we call toString on a StringType (defined from the type of the field).
The StringType toString methode is :

```
public String toString(Object value) {
    return (String) value;
}
```

Since the value has been retrieved through the getter, a ClassCastException is thrown.